# Examples: Infinite-dimensional simple Lie algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-algebras, examples-counterexamples, semisimple-lie-algebras

In my lecture notes it says that there exist infinite-dimensional simple Lie algebras.
What are examples of these? In what context do they come up? Is there a classification result analogous to the Cartan-Killing classification in the finite-dimensional complex case?

Comment: See, say, Baranov for the classical series of finitary simple Lie algebras, which are infinite-dimensional: $\mathfrak{sl}(\infty)$, $\mathfrak{so}(\infty)$ etc. For details see for example [here](https://www2.le.ac.uk/departments/mathematics/extranet/staff-material/staff-profiles/ab155/research/fin.pdf).

Comment: A classification, even assuming countable dimension or finite generation, sounds hopeless. However there are classification results under additional hypotheses (see for instance "Classification of simple graded Lie algebras of finite growth" by O. Mathieu, https://eudml.org/doc/144003).